# How to add a photo in the previous page after running a Python script

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have been trying to work on a web page, something simple, just to get my bearings since I am a true novice when it comes to all things web-related.

I have a main page in HTML with a form, allowing the user to upload a file, a Python script that does the uploading and, finally, a Javascript file which takes the data from the form and sends it to the Python script.

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(ev){
    ev = ev || event;
    ev.cancelBubble = true;
    ev.returnValue = false;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("fileobj", fileElem.filename); 
formdata.append("appearname", appearname);
formdata.append("appear", appear);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "upload.py");  
xhr.send(formdata);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var aux = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseXML );
        if ( {"estado" == "inserido"} )
        {
            img.src = aux.name;
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = fileElem.filename
            img.height = '100px' // por exemplo
            document.body.appendChild( img );
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as I intended, for it does not insert the image under the form, instead showing only the Python output.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Don't you think that python code will help?

Comment: Would you like me to post that as well? Sorry, I was afraid of cluttering up the post...

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a name in your form, like this (this is not mandatory):

```
<form name='test'>
    <input type='file' name='fileObj' />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you can use the javascript to "grab" the form and "send" it to the server (python script), like this:

```
document.forms[ 'test' ].onsubmit = function( ev ) {
    ev = ev || event;
    ev.cancelBubble = true;
    ev.returnValue = false;

    var data = new FormData( );
    data.append( 'fileobj' , this[ 'fileobj' ].files[ 0 ] );

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest( );
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );

    xmlhttp.open( "POST" , "upload.py" , true );

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function( ) {
        if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
            var aux = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );
            if ( aux.estado == 'inserido' ) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = aux.fname;
                img.style.height = '100px';
                document.body.appendChild( img );
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send( data );
}
```

You have to notice, samethings in the javascript code.
The 'this' is the form, then, when you do this[ 'fileobj' ], you "are in" the input, and the input element have an object with the files the user want upload, and then you can choose the first: this[ 'fileobj' ].files.
More, you thought well, but execute bad :)
All that code, have to be inside the function onsubmit. You want to send the file to the server when the user click the button in the form.
In the onreadystatechange, considering that the python script send an JSON with this info: { 'estado' : 'inserido' , 'fname' : 'path/to/file/name.file' }, you could verify if the response (aux), have a value 'inserido' for a key 'estado', and then use that object to create an image with the path and file name that was uploaded.

Looking quickly to the python script, you can have this:

```
import cgi
import json
import os

try:
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY)
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileElem = form['fileobj']

open( fileElem.filename , 'wb' ).write( fileElem.file.read() ) 

print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print json.dumps( { 'estado' : 'inserido' , 'fname' : fileElem.filename } )
```

In this, I'm not doing no type of verification of the input neither the writing of file...
but, the important thing is, you have to do that try if you don't know where your script will run (you need the msvcrt in windows). With the cgi.FieldStorage() you can get the input from the javascript, the form['fileobj'] get the file element (notice that, fileobj was the name that I set the formdata in javascript, not the name of the input of the form), then with the file element you can access to the filename (fileElem.filename) and the file it self (fileElem.file).

I hope I helped.